# Как записать объект одного класса в массив-объект другого класса Java

Tags: java

В общем, есть у меня класс Zoo, есть класс Aviary, в него надо запихнуть объекты класса Animals, при чем так, что бы не превышать максимальное число животных в вальере и дальнейшей работы с этим массивом каждой клетки отдельно. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Зачем зверей Animal запихивать в птичник Aviary?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите более подробную информацию, что вы пытались предпринять, и что не получилось. На данном сайте помощь с учебными заданиями оказывается лишь в том случае, когда приведены попытки их решения.

Comment: Как сказали - так и делаете. В классе `Aviary` создаете массив нужного типа `ArrayList<Animals>`.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сделать это средствами ООП, то лучше добавить в класс Aviary массив из объектов класса Animals, а также ограничение по количеству животных в вальере. А дальше работать с этим массивом при помощи соответствующих методов. Также можно добавить метод, который будет проверять количество животных в вальере и выдавать соответствующее сообщение, если число животных превышает допустимое.